# Change value of html element with external javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, external-js

Below is the div that I want to alter

```
<div id="@page.Page" class="pageMessages" data-messages='@Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(@page.Messages))'></div>
```

I want to change the value of the message when a javascipt function is called from an external .js file.  What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like So...

```
// This Performs the Change
$('#changeme').attr('data-messages', 'New Value');

// Show the Change
$('#changeme').html( $('#changeme').attr('data-messages') );
```

Here is a Working [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/A6N49/)

The one problem I see is the id='@page.Page'  , this doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i get what you're trying to do, you can use jquery's change attribute for that

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".pageMessages").attr("data-messages","your-new-value-here");
});
</script>
```

**DOC:** http://api.jquery.com/attr/